# ScheduledExecutorService: how to wait for all tasks to finish then execute more tasks

Tags: java, task

My code is like:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(8);

//complex code that call this multiple times too add tasks:
executor.schedule(() -> { doRealTask(); }, 0, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);

//drain the pool on some condition, e.g. meets tasks that can't be parallelized:
executor.shutdown();//without this, awaitTermination won't return since all the threads in the pool will be paused, not terminated
executor.awaitTermination(1000000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//continue to add more tasks:
executor.schedule(...);
```

java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException is thrown on the last code. The reason seems to be executor has been shutdown. But there is not a "startAgain" function. Obviously creating a new ScheduledExecutorService works but I feel that I'm using the wrong solution.

How to implement this in Java?

Comment: Why not use the futures that are returned when you call schedule? You can store them in a list and loop over them and use .get to essentially join your tasks.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @tmarwen Sending a lot of tasks to the pool to be executed by multiple thread, when meeting some task that can't be parallelized, first wait former tasks to complete then send it to the pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store you're futures in a list, then use get to effectively join.

```
List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

futures.add(executor.schedule(() -> { doRealTask(); }, 0, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS));
```

Instead of shutting down.

```
for(Future<?> future: futures){
    future.get();
}

futures.clear();
```

Now you need to handle an exception, and probably include a timeout on the get.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdowned state is irreversible, so just need to create a new executor if you need. There is no other way to reuse the previous one. But why do you need to shut it down if you're going to create it again? If it has too many tasks and you can sacrifice them in favor in new ones, then it makes sense to configure reasonable timeout for each task and configure the pool itself (for instance, pool and task queue size).

Each call of `Executor.schedule(() -> { doRealTask(); }, 0, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);` will return `ScheduledFuture` instance, you can store it and process the result later.